# Python how to read last three lines of a .txt file, and put those items into a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to have python read the last three lines of a .txt file.  I am also trying to add each line as an element in a list.

So for instance:

```
**list.txt**
line1
line2
line3

**python_program.py**
(read list.txt, insert items into line_list)
line_list[line1,line2,line3]
```

However I am a bit confused on this process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!  They all worked, and I will definitely keep the memory waste in mind Matteo Italia.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
line_list = lines[-3:]
```

Answer (score 5):

What if you are dealing with a very big file? Reading all the lines in memory is going to be quite wasteful. An alternative approach may be:

```
from collections import deque 
d=deque([], maxlen=3)
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
       d.append(l)
```

This keeps in memory at a given time only the last three rows read (the deque discards the oldest elements in excess at each append).

---

As @user2357112 points out, this will work as well, and is more synthetic:

```
from collections import deque 
d=None
with open("file.txt") as f:
    d=deque(f, maxlen=3)
```

Comment: `d = deque(f, maxlen=3)` would also work. It might not be faster - this is likely I/O-bound - but it's shorter. Whether or not it's clearer may depend on the reader.

Comment: @user2357112: that's way neater, I always forget that typically these constructors accept enumerables and not just lists. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint

def get_last_3_variant_1(file_):
    # This is simple, but it also reads the entire file into memory
    lines = file_.readlines()
    return lines[-3:]

def get_last_3_variant_2(file_):
    # This is more complex, but it only keeps three lines in memory at any given time
    three_lines = []
    for index, line in zip(range(3), file_):
        three_lines.append(line)

    for line in file_:
        three_lines.append(line)
        del three_lines[0]

    return three_lines

get_last_3 = get_last_3_variant_2

def main():
    # /etc/services is a long file
    # /etc/adjtime is exactly 3 lines long on my system
    # /etc/libao.conf is exactly 2 lines long on my system
    for filename in ['/etc/services', '/etc/adjtime', '/etc/libao.conf']:
        with open (filename, 'r') as file_:
            result = get_last_3(file_)
        pprint.pprint(result)

main()
```